# Pyramid and .ini configuration

Tags: python, configuration-files, pyramid, ini

Each Pyramid application has an associated .ini file that contains its settings. For example, a default might look like:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:MyProject
pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
...
```

I am wondering if it is possible to add your own configuration values in there, and read them at run-time (mostly from a view callable). For instance, I might want to have

```
[app:main]
blog.title = "Custom blog name"
blog.comments_enabled = true
...
```

Or is it better to have a separate .ini file and parse it during startup?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sure you can.

In your entry point function (`main(global_config, **settings)` in `__init__.py` in most cases), your config is accessible in the `settings` variable.

For example, in your `.ini`:

```
[app:main]
blog.title = "Custom blog name"
blog.comments_enabled = true
```

In your `__init__.py`:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    blog_title = settings['blog.title']
    # you can also access you settings via config
    comments_enabled = config.registry.settings['blog.comments_enabled']
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

According to the [latest Pyramid docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html#adding-a-custom-setting), you can access the settings in a view function via `request.registry.settings`. Also, as far as I know, it will be in event subscribers via `event.request.registry.settings`.

Regarding your question about using another file, I'm pretty sure it's good practice to put all your config in the regular init file, using dotted notation like you did.