# How to access the current config in a view handler?

Tags: pyramid

I want to use a config method ('absolute_asset_spec') in a view handler.
How do I get the config object to invoke it on?

I've seen talk of a Config() method but where is it defined? Searching for it is, shall we say, problematic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `request.registry.settings` what you are looking for?

More details here:

[Pyramid and .ini configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570930/pyramid-and-ini-configuration/7583431#7583431)

Or you were talking about a method. You want to access a method in every request?

```
def some_method():
   return 'stuff you want'

# in your main function
config.add_request_method(some_method, 'stuff', reify=True)

# in a view
foo = request.stuff
```

Comment: I actually want to invoke Configurator.absolute_asset_spec: [link](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.absolute_asset_spec)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointer. The answer is:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/home.pt')
def home_view(request):
  config = Configurator(registry=request.registry)
  path = config.absolute_asset_spec('__init__.py')
    :
    :
```